# Show sheet data in userform

Tags: excel

Sorry if this is posted before, couldn't find a simple guide / answer. I want to use a UserForm to show data form a different worksheet. I've used the following code:

```
Private Sub Label1_Click()

Label1.Caption = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

End Sub
```

When using this code the UserForm pops up, but it doesn't show the value at first. When I click on the Label it does.

Does anyone have experience with the issue? I don't want the user to first click on the Label to show the data, I want to show more Labels.

Comment: Use `UserForm_Initialize` method to set your label value. That way, everytime the form is launched, it will display your updated label

Comment: I am a novice to VBA, could you elaborate

Answer (score 1):

This method is only launched when you click the Label, that's why it is named Label1_Click().

If you want you can have a method like :

```
Private Sub SetLabel1()
    Label1.Caption = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

To show the UserForm:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

YourUserForm.Show

End Sub
```

And then call the SetLabel1 in the UserFormName_Initialize() subroutine:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    SetLabel1()
End Sub
```

When you use the Show method for the Userform, this sub will automatically be executed.

Comment: Not quite getting it right. When I create a new Label in my User Form, and want to add code, it automatically cerate's a Click variant. Naming the Sub: SetLabel only gives a error.

Comment: This is all I have at the moment. I want to expand after this. At this point I want to press a button and have a user form pop-up with data that is shown in a different workbook.

Comment: @Peter try to call the method from UserForm_Initiazlieze() as i showed in the edit.

Comment: I'm getting a error saying it is missing a '=' with the subroutine (Private sub UserForm_Initializer). I have a sub were I call the userform. In my case: userform3.show

Comment: Initialize? or InitializeR?